# Flutter 2.0: How to create a model class for firestore snapshot

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I construct a flutter class for firestore snapshot for flutter 2.0

I tried something like this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Post {
  final String pid;
  final String description;

  final DocumentReference reference;

  Post.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, this.pid, this.description, {required this.reference})

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Post<$pid:$description>";
}
```

But there is an error saying 3 positional arguments expected but 1 found.

Comment: Please provide full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not passing `pid` and `description` (which were positional parameters). You could either make them optional named parameter or pass them explicitly.

**Solution 1 (making parameters optional):**

```dart
class Post {
  final String pid;
  final String description;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(
          snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
          reference: snapshot.reference,
        );

  Post.fromMap(
    Map<String, dynamic> map, {
    required this.reference,
    this.pid = 'dummyID',
    this.description = 'dummyDesc',
  });

  @override
  String toString() => 'Post<$pid:$description>';
}
```

**Solution 2 (passing parameters):**

```
class Post {
  final String pid;
  final String description;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(
          snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
          'pid',
          'description',
          reference: snapshot.reference,
        );

  Post.fromMap(
    Map<String, dynamic> map,
    this.pid,
    this.description, {
    required this.reference,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => 'Post<$pid:$description>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `3 positional arguments expected but 1 found` is there because in your `Post.fromMap` there are three arguments (snapshot, pid, description) that are required to call this. There is also a 4th one (reference) that is marked `required`.
But when you are calling this in `fromSnapshot`, you are only giving two parameters when the required are four.

This is the most common way to define a model.
You can create other member functions as required.

`DocumentReference reference` field should be nullable in my opinion in case data is not from firebase.

```dart
class Post {
  final String pid;
  final String description;

  final DocumentReference? reference;

  Post({
    required this.pid,
    required this.description,
    required this.reference,
  });

  factory Post.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {required DocumentReference? reference}) {
    return Post(
        pid: map['pid'], 
        description: map['description'],
        reference: reference,
    );
  }

  factory Post.fromSnapshot(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot) =>
      Post.fromMap(snapshot, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Post<$pid:$description>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like below:

```
class Post {
  final String pid;
  final String description;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(
          snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
          reference: snapshot.reference,
        );

  Post.fromMap(
    Map<String, dynamic> map, {
    required this.reference,
  })  : pid = map['pid'],
        description = map['description'];

  @override
  String toString() => 'Post<$pid:$description>';
}
```